# How do I enable spell check on my sublime language file?

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, spell-checking, sublime-text-plugin

I wrote my own `.tmLanguage` file for sublime, but I can't figure out how to enable spell checking for it. Spell checking must be an option encoded in the language file, because not everything would require checking (usually just comments).

I can't find any documentation that mentions how one would target particular keys to require spell checking. It must rely on some kind of attribute or key name?

I don't think it has anything to do with settings: `"spell_check": true` is already enabled in the preferences.

Comment: Have you tried setting `"spell_check": true` in the syntax-specific settings, as opposed to just the general preferences? (Open a document that uses your new language syntax, open the Preferences menu > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User and add it there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `tmLanguage` file looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>fileTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>LanguageName</string>
        </array>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>LanguageName</string>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>begin</key>
                <string>(</string>
                <key>end</key>
                <string>)</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TOKEN_NAME</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>scopeName</key>
        <string>source.Language</string>
        <key>uuid</key>
        <string>172ddd2d-11e8-45b2-a3cc-cjf1ffa60e56</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

It turns out that, my `scopeName` needed to be:
`<string>text.Language</string>` instead of `<string>source.Language</string>`.

*The `.Language` is my language file extension, and yours will vary.